# Azure Bot Service using over 1GB of data transfer out per day. Why? How can I stop that?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-web-app-service

I created a QnA bot using the Azure Bot service, and now I'm seeing data transfers out of my subscription of over 1 GB a day! I cannot figure out why, but since it's billable, I'd like to know why and how I can stop it.

The bot isn't being used yet, so no one is sending queries to it. I'm confused how this is happening.

Here's a screen shot of the graph for use in the last hour as well as a screen shot of the billing for the last few days showing the sudden jump in use.

Is this normal?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage` with a value of `true`, to the **App settings**, the data out will stop.

The setting itself is documented here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Configuration-Settings (although it doesn't provide an explanation for how this setting affects a bot specifically)

The reasoning behind what is happening is a little complex.  Azure Functions are not normally "in memory" and available all the time.  There is a small spinup time that is not ideal within a bot.  So, apparently there is a job setup with consumption plan bots to ping it every 10 seconds (and by 'ping', i mean retrieve the root of the site).  If you open the Log Stream, you'll see an http get request every 10 seconds.  Adding AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage doesn't disable the request, but changes the status of what is returned from "OK" to "NoContent".

This will be added to the Bot Service arm template soon (so future consumption plan bots do not automatically accrue these data usages).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I ended up just deleting the bot, but I may try creating one again and testing it.